# How to read line after finding a pattern?

Tags: perl

I've got the lines

```
CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
id=3
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the id after I do a search on the file and found the first line.

```
open(CHECKFILE8, "$file");
while (<CHECKFILE8>) {             #while loop to loop through each line in the file
    chomp;                         #take out each line by line
    $datavalue = $_;               #store into var , $datavalue.
    $datavalue =~ s/^\s+//;        #Remove multiple spaces and change to 1 space from the front
    $datavalue =~ s/\s+$//;        #Remove multiple spaces and change to 1 space from the back
    $datavalue =~ s/[ \t]+/ /g;    #remove multiple "tabs" and replace with 1 space
    if ($datavalue eq "CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)") {
        # HOW TO READ THE NEXT LINE?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you're reading all of the other lines: with the expression `<CHECKFILE8>`.  For example:

```
my $nextline = <CHECKFILE8>;
```

You should be aware, though, that opening filehandles via a bareword identifier is somewhat archaic Perl.  It's generally safer and more idiomatic to let Perl create filehandles in lexically scoped variables for you:

```
open my $checkfile8, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
while (<$checkfile8>) { ... }
```

You are using `use strict`, right?